# flatMap(func) versus flatMap(func(_))

Tags: scala

I'm very surprised by not being able to find an existing question for that one. Why is that, given:

```
val p: Int => Option[Int] = Some(_)
List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(p)
```

I'm getting:

```
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Option[Int]
 required: Int => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
       List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(p)
```

But if I replace last line with this one, it compiles and works as expected:

```
List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(p(_))
```

My take on the problem is that in case of `p(_)` the type inference system kicks in to decide on the type of lambda, and on the way it finds appropriate implicit conversion for `Option[Int]` (`option2Iterable`, I believe). With just `p`, the type is already known, and it's incorrect, so no conversion is attempted (and there's no conversion for `Function1` returning `Option` to `Function1` returning `GenTraversableOnce`).

Is this reasoning right? And if so, is there some reason why I shouldn't report this as a bug/issue?

EDIT: A new twist: I've seen `p.apply` mentioned in some (sadly) deleted comment (though this was about coding style). Surprisingly, it works just as well as `p(_)` does.

Comment: I think the reasoning is right. You could confirm this by defining the implicit conversion between functions yourself? You can report anything as an issue, the more interesting bit is what will happen to the issue after you do :)

Comment: Interestingly, defining an implicit conversion between functions tricks IntelliJ IDEA's code analyzer, but doesn't persuade the compiler to summon the implicit for this case :) `implicit def fun1TR1toFun1TR2[T, R1, R2](fun: T => R1)(implicit view: R1 => R2): T => R2 =  fun andThen view`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you type `List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(p(_))` what's done behind the scenes is that function `p` gets spawned and wrapped in another function that partially applies it - meaning all necessary implicit conversions, if any, will also get applied inside the body of this new function.

When you type `List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(p)`, no function application happens, and you try to pass an `Int => Option[Int]` which is incompatible with the signature `Int => GenTraversableOnce[Int]`, and although the scope contains an implicit conversion from `Option[T]` to `Iterable[T]`, there's no conversion from `Function1[Int, Option[Int]]` to `Function1[Int, Iterable[Int]]` defined.

The reason for that, probably, is because functions of arbitrary arity have virtually infinite amount of variations due to generics, and since `Function`s do not share a supertrait, that would require quite a bunch of implicits for each type of functions.

---

Here's a construct that extends `flatMap` just enough to achieve the desired result for `p`. However, it makes the already obscure signature of `flatMap` even less clear (much less clear). I believe, there's no technical block from implementing this behavior, but complexity of signatures is the reason why scala-collections library is often hailed.

```
import scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit class ListEx[A](list: List[A]) {
  def flatMap2[B, M[_], That](f: A => M[B])
                             (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That],
                                       view: M[B] => GenTraversableOnce[B]): That =
    list.flatMap(f andThen view)
}

val p: Int => Option[Int] = Some(_)

List(1, 2, 3) flatMap2 p
```

Comment: So it seems to follow the same reasoning as mine. One thing, though; it's reasonable not to expect conversions for all the functions, just as you say - but I think that the compiler, which does all the implicit-fu, could attempt to implicitly convert just the return value. The only reason I know for not doing that is the additional time cost during compilation, and I'd love to know if there's any other.

Comment: I don't see any technical reasons why this cannot be implemented - maybe it's just not worth it, considering you can always make a partial function. I updated my answer with an illustration of even more obscure `flatMap` signature incorporating the desired implicit resolution.

Answer (score 4):

```
List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(p(_))
```

is compiled to:

```
List(1,2,3).flatMap(x => p(x))
```

And as `p(x)` is returning `Option[Int]` and `flatMap` needs `GenTraversableOnce[Int]` so `scala.Option.option2Iterable` is applied.

Option does not inherit from `GenTraversableOnce`. To make this syntax work:

```
List(1,2,3).flatMap(p)
```

you need implicit convertion from `Int => Option[Int]` to `Int => GenTraversableOnce[Int]`, sth like this:

```
import scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce

implicit def conv(c: Int => Option[Int]): Int => GenTraversableOnce[Int] = {
    a => Option.option2Iterable(c(a))
}
val p: Int => Option[Int] = Some(_)
List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(p)
```

For me this is not a bug, but I agree, it's not intuitive either.